# Wrapping boost::shared_ptr in PHP using SWIG

Tags: php, swig, shared-ptr, php-extension

If I use SWIG to wrap this C++ function:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Client> Client::create() {
    return boost::shared_ptr<Client>(new Client());
}
```

And then call it in PHP:

```
$client = Client::create();
echo gettype($client);
```

The type of `$client` is `resource`, not `object`, and so I cannot call `Client` methods.

What are my options for wrapping this function? I'm creating a PHP wrapper for someone else's C++ library, so reworking the code to not use `boost::shared_ptr` isn't really an option.

This is the only solution I've come up with so far:

```
MyClient Client::createObject() {
    return *Client::create();
}
```

And calling it in PHP:

```
$client = Client::createObject();
echo gettype($client);
```

Now the type of `$client` is `object` and I can call `Client` methods on it. Is this a reasonable workaround? If not, what should I be doing?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_smart_pointers ;)